# Download spring reference documentation

Tags: spring

Since the redesign of springsource.org, I am no long able to find the reference documentation available for download.  Previously, you could download the source archive (which contained all the code) and it would also have the reference docs available for offline use.  This was really helpful.

Is this available somewhere else now?  As a note, I'm looking for the reference documentation (the user guide - i.e. what is found at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/) - not the API (javadoc) docs...those are available via maven central.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf for the PDF version.

Comment: Their servers seems to fall a lot.

Comment: https://zealdocs.org is a nice tool for downloading a variety of offline documentations, the Spring Framework being among them.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a directory listing when you delete part of the path.

An archived copy of the Spring Framework Reference Documentation (for version 4.1.0) can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140922232930/http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/spring-framework-reference.pdf).

Comment: Yeah - I actually want the individual (separate) html files...not the single html file or the pdf file (either of which are easily downloadable).  Problem is that if you go to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/, the index page is served - instead of the directory listing.

Comment: Though I may just have to suck it up and use the single HTML file (I don't like to though - because it's so big it gets unwieldy to search through when I'm looking for something)